# Active Record issue in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to do db:migrate but I get this error:

DEPRECATION WARNING: require "activerecord" is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 3. Use require "active_record" instead. (called from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/activerecord.rb:2)

What's the problem? I'm using Rails 3.0.9 with Ruby 1.8.7 & Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: Presumably your app is requiring 'activerecord' somewhere, either in the Gemfile, in a config, or perhaps in a plugin.  Can you tell which active record version it's trying to load?

Comment: What if you run: bundle exec rake db:migrate

Comment: What version of activerecord does it say you're using? This was an issue in 2.x

Comment: copy-paste your **Gemfile.lock** here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your `Gemfile.lock` and do `bundle install` once again.